# How should i handle the lazily initialized Hibernate entities in dao layer and sharing state in diferrent layers

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, dao

i am writing a web application(server based application) where i am having a dao layer, the service layer and the application layer. how should i take over the lazy initialization exception, caused due to the fact that entity returned from dao layer is concerned with the session opened inside the method from where it is returned and also closed there which makes the entity detached.
Next thing is it safe to share the hibernate entities across different layer. what makes me to ask this question is the scenario: for example suppose i am having a hibernate entity having one to one association with some other entity. and suppose dao passed it to the service layer to the application layer. now if i try to get this associated entity in application layer through the passed entity getter method, a database query is fired which i think is messing up with the "seperation of concerns" as database related operation should be constrained to the dao layer. am i right?

i have discovered the mentioned problem during the time i am unit testing my dao layer through in-memory database. My scenario is, i am having one of the pojo class called RegisteredUser having the fields: (id, username, firstname, lastname, passwHash, email, StudyCentre). StudyCentre is an another entity which is assosciated with RegistereUser by one to one mapping and username is the naturalid.
What i want is 2 types of read operation, first one is i need to get user details without studycentre through natural id and second one is getting the complete user fields again through naturalid. is making two seperate DTOs a good idea here and passing them across layers.

RegisteredUser Entity:

```java
package com.ignoubadhega.pojos;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId;

@Entity
@Table(name = "registered_user")
@DynamicUpdate
public class RegisteredUser {

    private Long dbUserId;
    private String userName;
    private String passwHash;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private StudyCentre studyCentre;

    RegisteredUser() {
    }

    public RegisteredUser(
            String userName, String passwHash, String firstName,
            String lastName, String email
    ) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passwHash = passwHash;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "db_user_id")
    public Long getDbUserId() {
        return dbUserId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RegisteredUser [dbUserId="
               + dbUserId
               + ", userName="
               + userName
               + ", passwHash="
               + passwHash
               + ", firstName="
               + firstName
               + ", lastName="
               + lastName
               + ", email="
               + email
               + "]";
    }

    public void setDbUserId(Long dbUserId) {
        this.dbUserId = dbUserId;
    }

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NaturalId
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "passw_hash", nullable = false)
    public String getPasswHash() {
        return passwHash;
    }

    public void setPasswHash(String passwHash) {
        this.passwHash = passwHash;
    }

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "db_study_centre_id", nullable = false)
    public StudyCentre getStudyCentre() {
        return studyCentre;
    }

    public void setStudyCentre(StudyCentre studyCentre) {
        this.studyCentre = studyCentre;
    }

}
```

Dao Implementor:

```java
package com.ignoubadhega.dao.impl;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.ignoubadhega.dao.RegisteredUserDAO;
import com.ignoubadhega.pojos.RegisteredUser;

public class RegisteredUserDAOImpl implements RegisteredUserDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public RegisteredUserDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(RegisteredUser user) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory
                .openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException except) {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RegisteredUser getUserByUserName(String username, boolean doesStudyCentereNeeded) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory
                .openSession()) {
            RegisteredUser user = session
                    .bySimpleNaturalId(RegisteredUser.class).load(username);
            if (doesStudyCentereNeeded) {
                user.setStudyCentre(user.getStudyCentre());
            }
            return user;
        } catch (HibernateException except) {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(RegisteredUser user) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory
                .openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException except) {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(RegisteredUser user) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory
                .openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException except) {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

TestCase which finds the problem of lazy initalization:

```java
@Test
@DisplayName(
    "User through its natural id 'username' assuming the user"
        + " is persistent in the database is successful"
)
void test_fetching_a_persistent_user_through_username_is_successful() {
    try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        RegisteredUser retrievedUser =
                dao.getUserByUserName("prav", true);
        assertNotNull(retrievedUser);
        assert_actual_user_and_retrieved_user_fields_are_equal(user,
                retrievedUser);
    } catch (HibernateException except) {
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void assert_actual_user_and_retrieved_user_fields_are_equal(
        RegisteredUser actualUser, RegisteredUser userRetrieved
) throws MultipleFailuresError {
    assertAll("user fields",
            () -> assertEquals(actualUser.getUserName(),
                    userRetrieved.getUserName()),
            () -> assertEquals(actualUser.getPasswHash(),
                    userRetrieved.getPasswHash()),
            () -> assertEquals(actualUser.getFirstName(),
                    userRetrieved.getFirstName()),
            () -> assertEquals(actualUser.getLastName(),
                    userRetrieved.getLastName()),
            () -> assertEquals(actualUser.getEmail(),
                    userRetrieved.getEmail()),
            () -> {
                StudyCentre retrievedCentre =
                        userRetrieved.getStudyCentre();
                assertNotNull(retrievedCentre);
                assertAll("user study centre assosciated",
                        () -> assertEquals(
                                actualUser.getStudyCentre().getData()
                                        .getStudyCentreName(),
                                retrievedCentre.getData()
                                        .getStudyCentreName()),
                        () -> assertEquals(
                                actualUser.getStudyCentre().getData()
                                        .getRegionalCentreCode(),
                                retrievedCentre.getData()
                                        .getRegionalCentreCode()));
            });
}
```

i want to keep my service layer(not yet implemented) to be isolated from things specific to hibernate like sessions and database related operations(CRUD). how can i achieve it. is there any design patterns i should follow. i am new to hibernate. please guide me if i am doing something wrong any where. i have tried finding the similar threads on google but failed to get any insights about the issue.

Comment: What's the difference between the service and the application layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how should i take over the lazy initialization exception, caused due to the fact that entity returned from dao layer is concerned with the session opened inside the method from where it is returned and also closed there which makes the entity detached.

You would deal with that by opening and closing the session in the service or the application layer, and doing all the work in a single transaction.

> is it safe to share the hibernate entities across different layer

Yes. What is not safe is to use an entity instance across several threads, because entities are not thread-safe.

> a database query is fired which i think is messing up with the "seperation of concerns" as database related operation should be constrained to the dao layer. am i right?

No. The service layer doesn't contain any code to trigger this database query. It happens transparently, without the service layer having to care about it, and because you chose to make the association lazy.

> is making two seperate DTOs a good idea here and passing them across layers.

No. DTOs are useful to transfer data between separate applications. Inside your application, working with managed entities is the correct way.

> i want to keep my service layer(not yet implemented) to be isolated from things specific to hibernate like sessions and database related operations(CRUD). how can i achieve it.

By using Spring or Java EE (or any other framework that has this feature) which allow using declarative transactions and deal with the task of opening/closing sessions and transactions for you whenever a transactional method is called.

You should also avoid using the proprietary Session API, and use the standard JPA API instead.

Comment: As you adviced opening and closing session each time for lazy initialization, will i have to update the detached instance again for making it persistent. if yes, then it is a CRUD call(in service or application layer) which will introduce some sort of coupling b/w layers as i am depending on the state of the object passed to seperate layers. also CRUD call in service layer or application layer doesn't seems a good idea. what is your opinion.

Comment: *As you adviced opening and closing session each time for lazy initialization, will i have to update the detached instance again for making it persistent.*: I didn't advise that. I advised using Spring or Java EE to use declarative transactions, and let the framework open the session before entering the application or service layer rather than entering the DAO layer. You shouldn't use detached instances anywhere.